# Copy and paste tables to PowerPoint issues

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

copying objects from excel to PowerPoint slides brings erratic results, from runtime errors to wrong format errors or not copying at all objects the code is supposed to copy.
This is a known issue, identified on the web, the origin of which seeming to be that the VBA code is running faster than the copy-paste system routine. The solution seems to bring pause to the code to let the copy-paste instruction to be achieved. Unfortunately, despite the following pausing possibilities, I still meet problems, especially when copying tables and pasting in default format. Then, the tables are copied, but with the original table format forgotten (especially table background colors). I do not meet this issue when copying in picture format.
Here is the pasting code extract, with different tries (other tries are commented):

```
For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
'Sleep 500
'pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
'pptApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
Set MyShape = theSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=typeDonnée)(1)
For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
'Sleep 500
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Anyone has an idea about the reamining issue?

Comment: Try putting the Paste part of the code in a different subroutine in a different module.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention it is already in a subroutine..

Comment: I see. In that case I'm not sure what else to suggest, but this is a fairly common question on SO. You might want to search (e.g. for the error message text) to see what others have suggested.